# how to select all checkbox from tablesorter

Tags: jquery, checkbox, tablesorter

This [table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) works perfect for me except when I added pagination plugin, I could only access checkboxs at the current page. Would really appreciate any help.

```
$("table#sortTableExample")
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true})
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false });


$('#select-all').live('click', function(){
     var $checkbox = $('.checkbox');
     $checkbox.prop('checked', 'checked');
     $(this).hide();
     $('#unselect-all').show();
});


$('#unselect-all').live('click', function(){
     var $checkbox = $('.checkbox');
     $checkbox.prop('checked', '')
     $(this).hide();
 $('#select-all').show();
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live()` is deprecated.

Comment: @Purmou I use jquery-1.6.min.js

Comment: In case you want to upgrade to 1.7, keep in mind that `live()`, `bind()`, and `delegate()` have been replaced with [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also, I get your problem now--you want to select the checkboxes present in every row, but the pager is preventing you from targeting the checkboxes that are currently not visible?

Comment: @Purmou Yes. that's the problem I have.

Comment: Tablesorter is a very tricky plugin that I regret ever having used...its documentation is absolutely lacking and getting the pager to work is a nightmare. If I were you I'd switch to a different table pager that probably offers support for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Why don't you try out something that's way better documented and maintained like datatables - http://datatables.net/

Comment: Regarding your problem, you'll need to save a flag somewhere that says 'select-all' is clicked or 'unselect-all' is clicked. Each time, you change the page in tablesorter, you'll need to look up this value and check/un-check the checkboxes.

Comment: @techfoobar it depends what those checkboxes are doing. With a solution like that he hasn't really checked the boxes, just made some kind of stop-gap measure which prevents an unchecked box from displaying. What if the information is being accessed through another channel? To "check" the boxes you will have to alter the JS object where tablesorter stores the real information that builds the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the pager plugin for tablesorter completely removes the unseen rows from the table. The content is stored and sorted from memory making it much faster to sort large tables.

I felt the same as @Purmou in that the original documentation was lacking, so I've added a lot more [documentation and demos](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) in my [fork of the tablesorter plugin on github](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter).

So, to solve your issue, I've modified the pager plugin to only hide the table rows instead of removing them completely. Set the `removeRows` option to `false` as in [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html). The main problem is that large tables will sort much slower. Oh, and you won't need to use `live()` either.

Comment: I've added removeRows false but it's still not working. this is my table jquery.  $("table#sortTableExample")
  .tablesorter({widthFixed: true})
  .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false, removeRows: false});

Comment: Sorry I didn't have the latest pager.js.  your solution works.